# No sound in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, alsa

I have strange problem. After installing Ubuntu Studio, I had no sound and after changing default card in alsa I have it but only in players. In web browsers (Firefox, Chromium), I have sound only on root account.

AlsaMixer default card.
[image]

And her QasMixer default card (on root account I have something like on the 1st pic).
[image]

I hope you will understand about what I am talking about and thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The op solved it by running this command in a terminal. `pacmd set-default-sink`, the answer was in the question by the OP.